# Adobe Flash CS5 - Is it possible to transfer all frames from a Movie clip to the stage?

Tags: flash-cs5

Is it possible to move all frames (including the frames on which classical tween/ motion tween is applied) from a movie clip to the stage?
Actually I did the entire animation within a single frame on stage, now when I try to export png sequence/avi clip, it renders just the first frame. Total frames within that frame on stage are around 900 frames. Please help I have tried everything for last one week now.

Thanks